# Facebook Fan, style the look - Don't work

Tags: css, facebook, facebook-page

I have a Facebook Fan API on my site, I want to style it myself, but I doesn't seem to work.
I do set the `CSS` to the CSS file on the ftp, but it's like the fan box done take usage of it.

Anyone knows what the problem is?

**Fan Box:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php/en_US"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">FB.init("");</script>
<fb:fan profile_id="145883417064" stream="0" connections="14" width="500px" height="600px" header="0" logobar="0" css="css=MY_URL/Facebook_CSS/fb_css.css">
</fb:fan>
```

**CSS:**

```
...
.fan_box .full_widget .connect_top {
    background:green !important; <--Green for testing
    padding:0 0 10px 0 !important;
}
...
```

**This is what CSS I get, when I refresh the page:**

```
.fan_box .full_widget .connect_top {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ECEFF5;
}
```

**And its coming from this CSS file:** `ZZOSKCuiTWq.css (linje 7)` and I have no idea where its coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook caches the css each time, append a different query string to the url of the css each time you make a change and it will pick it up. Here's a guide that helped me do the same http://www.daddydesign.com/wordpress/how-to-customize-your-facebook-fan-box/

Comment: How in hell did i miss that part O.o